# I can't integrate asymptote with TeXShop

Tags: mac, texshop, asymptote

I'm trying to use Asymptote with TeXShop on Mac OS X 10.8.5. I'm attempting to follow the instructions given at http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/TeXShopAndAsymptote.pdf

I got through step 2, but when it came to step 3, creating the asymptote engine, I discovered that I didn't have a folder called `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`. I didn't even have a folder called `~/Library/TeXShop`.

So I created both folders, then created a text file with the code specified in step 3 of the above document and saved it as `asyEngine.Engine`. Then I finished steps 4 and 5, but no `asyEngine` appears in my drop-down list of engines in TeXShop. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The `~` stands for your *home*; open a Finder window and type Command+Shift+G; in the box that appears, type `~/Library/TeXshop`, you'll be taken in the right folder.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Chad: You have a typo in your question's file. `asyEngine.Engine` should be called `asyEngine.engine` instead, as your instructions say.

Comment: The Go to Folder command produced a "folder could not be found error."  For some reason, the folder was not created during TeXShop installation.  Thinking that the .engine files might have been installed somewhere else, I did a spotlight search for the extension .engine.  No results.  It seems that no .engine files were created during the TeXShop (v 3.26) installation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to create the `~/Library/Engines` folder, since it is created automatically by TeXShop, which means, as suggested in the comments that you have misunderstood something about the folder.

Go open a Finder window, an type Command-Shif-G.  This will open a box into which you can type any path.

Into the box type:

```
~/Library/TeXshop
```

[image]

The TeXShop library folder will then appear in the finder window:

[image]

Inside this folder there is an Engines folder which contains all the active Engines.  There is also a folder named `Inactive`.  Go into that folder, and you will find an `Asymptote` folder.  Move the `Asymptote.engine` file you find there to the main Engines folder, and restart TeXShop.  Your new engine will then be available in the dropdown menu.

Comment: I understand that TeXShop should have created the directory ~/Library/TeXShop and the subdirectory ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines.  However, when I installed TeXShop (v 3.26), these directories were apparently not created for some reason.  The "go to folder" command in finder produces a "folder can't be found" error.  Any ideas why the folder wouldn't be created during TeXShop installation?

Comment: @chad That's very odd, since TeXShop uses those folders itself.  And TeXShop is working otherwise, I assume. If you want I can set up a chatroom to help you directly.

Comment: @chad Hopefully you can join this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12710/discussion-between-alan-and-chad

Comment: Not the appropriate place to post, I realize, but I need at least 20 reputation to participate in chat.  As a new user I only have six.

Comment: Problem solved:  the issue was simply that, as a novice mac user, I didn't enter the tilde in the Go To Folder command.

Comment: @Chad: In the ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/inactive/latexmk folder you should find something that you could be very useful to you: `asymptotemk.engine`. As described previously, drag it into the main Engines folder and restart TeXShop. It will be also available in the Engines dropdrown. This `asymptotemk.engine` automatizes the typesetting of your LaTeX file and its Asymptote drawings: each time something is modified in the code of your drawings, a triple compilation (like in AsyEngine.engine) is launched by this script, otherwise it does only the classical(s) LaTeX compilation(s).